# nativescript fails to run with an exit code of 0

Tags: nativescript

I've started having problems getting nativescript to run, and the error message is truly confusing, since it is exit code 0.

```
tns run android
Searching for devices...
NativeScript Environment:  tns run <platform> --env not provided.
NativeScript Environment:  Environment vars not changed
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.
```

I've tried the usual suspect list of remedies: uninstall/reinstall nativescript, platforms, etc.  `tns doctor` gives me a full green-checkmark bill of clean health.
This just started happening today. I've been using it without this problem for over a year of development prior.
What should I try next?

Comment: Are you on Windows / Mac? Which version of Node, {N} CLI & runtime you are using?

Comment: Mac (Mojave 10.14.6), Node v10.1.0, Nativescript tns 6.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is working again now for me.
Here's what I found:

- I found I was able to build a different project without issue, but not my main work.
- After other messing about, I finally was given an error message that complained that my webpack.config.js was different than that of one of my plugins. It suggested I run ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs to revert to an approved configuration.
- I did that, and it worked.  *However*, I had deliberately modified my webpack config some time ago to allow some app-specific files to transfer, as shown below.
- I put my custom 'globs' lines back in and it still works, although this is the same as where it was when the whole affair started.
- go figure.

```
// Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.json" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.map" } }
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

(the *.json and *.map entries are my additions).  As the comment implies, this appears to be an encouraged form of config modification for this purpose.

Comment: **UPDATE** STILL BROKEN

It happened to me again.
Not sure why, just like before.

But this time, the steps I followed above (revert the webpack.config.js file) did not solve the problem.  It's still refusing to run with the totally unhelpful output `Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.`

Note that this happens for both android and iOS builds.

So I am stuck again.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!