# Can't deploy NativeScript to iOS after latest Xcode update?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I am using NativeScript 6.4.1 and am up to date, with iOS platform version 6.4.2

I have been building and deploying to my IOS device regularly.  But today I find I can't.  It simply hangs trying to install the app (It does manage to force the previous version of the app to uninstall, so now I don't even have the old version on my phone).

Yes, I have the provisioning all set properly.  If I change any of that, I get an error, as expected.  Here, with everything in place, I get no error, just a hang:

```xml
Project successfully built.
The build result is located at: /Users/sohmert/tbd/sniff/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/sniff.ipa
Installing on device 000080XX-000XXXXX3A92XXX...
```

I can still run it on the iOS emulator.  But I need to get it on my device again for some real-world testing.

About the only thing I can think of that has changed in the past few days for me is that I did do a series of updates that included an update to Xcode.  Xcode currently reports as version 11.4.  Could that be the problem? If so what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay -- I got past this one.
Like some other problems ([nativescript fails to run with an exit code of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348270/nativescript-fails-to-run-with-an-exit-code-of-0)), and an android build problem related to conflicts with duplicate static class names, the problem can be solved if I do a full fresh git clone of my repository into a new directory and building from there.  Obviously, there is some issue with a generated file somewhere along the line, but I haven't done a full diff analysis or anything to figure out what.
Anyway -- if anyone else has similar issues, try starting from a completely new state like this.
Maybe in some glorious future, these mystery problems with using NativeScript will be thing of distant memory, but for now, a series of voodoo workarounds to get through the day appear to be the norm from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Update nativescript with latest version 6.5.0 and update your project with using this command **tns update**. Install latest version **Xcode11** in your mac with latest iOS version sdk13.